# Run mkvirtualenv command as another user

Tags: sudo, su, virtualenv

I want to run the "mkvirtual sth" but I have to run the script as superuser.

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

install.sh looks like this:

```
# ...
mkvirtualenv sth
# su - geeret -c "mkvirtualenv sth" # (tried this)
# ...
```

both returns **su: mkvirtualenv: command not found**

When I am logged in as geeret I can run mkvirtualenv without any problems. I think virtualenevwrapper(mkvirtualenv) is installed only for geeret, how can I tell the root what to do?

I thought about using the full path to the command but **which mkvirtualenv** returns an empty string.